# Falling rearrangement of a measurable function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f: X \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ measurable. The falling rearrangement of $f$ is defined by: $g: [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty], g(t) := \mu (\{x \in X: f(x) \geq t \})$.

How can I show $\int_{\chi} f d \mu = \int_{[0, \infty)} g d \lambda$ ?

(where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure)

I know that a possible way to show this would be to use the lemma of Fubini. But the problem is that we should not use this lemma for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write, $$E=\{(x,y)\in X\times\Bbb R:0\leq y\leq f(x)\}.$$ Now

$$\int_Xf(x)\mu(dx)=\int_X\lambda(E_x)\mu(dx)$$$$=\mu\times \lambda(E)$$$$=\int_{\Bbb R}\mu(E^y)\lambda(dy)=\int_0^{\infty}\mu\big(\{x\in X:f(x)\geq y\}\big)dy$$